# The Usage of "Would"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

"The mission control experts cannot tell if the space junk is going to hit the space station or not, but they are sure that a collision **would** knock a hole in the hull and cause all air inside it to quickly escape into space."

What does "would" give a particular meaning in this context? I think **assumption/expectation** is meant. *They assume that a collision knocks a hole in the hull. They expect a collision to knock a hole in the hull.*

Is it common the such usage of would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Would** in the OP sentence has a conditional sense. The implied condition is space junk hitting the station: if that happens, other outcomes will follow.

So you are not correct to read it as *They assume that a collision knocks a hole in the hull*. If you read the whole text again you will see they are not **assuming** this, they are **sure** of it. If event A happens, event B will certainly follow. But **would** is used here because they don't know whether event A (the collision) will happen.

Yes, this is a normal usage of the word.